# The basis of the combination of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently reading through Halmos' Finite dimensional vector spaces. On page 18 a theorem (corollory) is stated based on a previous theorem. This previous theorem states that "*If $S$ is any set of vectors in a vector space $V$ and if $M$ is the subspace spanned by $S$, then $M$ is equivalent to the set of all linear combinations of the elements in $S$.

This makes sense to me, but the corollory is the following: "*If $K$ and $X$ are any two subspaces, and $M$ is the subspace spanned by $K$ and $X$ together* (I had to assume the author here means the union of $X$ and $K$)*, then $M$ is equivalent to the set of all vectors of the form $x + k$, where $x\in{X}$ and $k\in{K}$.*

But then, surely, the corollory is identical to the theorem if the union of $X$ and $K$ is equal to $S$, then $M$ is spanned by $X\cup{K}$, and by the theorem, $M$ is equivalent to the linear combination of all the vectors in $S$. Then, rather than just $x + k$, should it not be $a\cdot x + b\cdot k$?

Is it the linear combination of $x$ and $k$ or just the elements of $x$ and $k$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X $ and  $K $ are subspaces, the set of all $x+k $ is the same as the set of all  $ax+bk $ (by closure under scalar multiplication).

Answer (score 0):

Here the notation $x+k$ means that the generic element of the spanned subspace $M$ can be written as a generic sum of an element of $X$ plus one of $K$. Indeed $M$ is generated, as you say, by the union $X\cup K$, thus it's pretty clear the result holds.

The theorem is basically telling you $M$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ which contains both $X$ and $K$, so it's nothing unexpected its elements are written as $x+k$. Just observe that $M$ needs to contain $X$ and $K$, thus since $M$ is a subspace it must contain sums of elements of $X$ and $K$.